# How to center sidebar vertically without using position absolute/fixed or flexbox (oldschool way)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, sidebar

I need to center sidebar vertically without using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, and also not using any css3 features, like flexbox and grid. I also may only use `div`, `ul`, and `li` elements. How can I do this?

Also, how can I position the footer at the bottom of the page with the same limitations?

This is my current solution using `position: fixed`: https://jsfiddle.net/gx82v4uo/

```
 .vertical-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0px;
}
.vertical-menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2b3b75;
}
.vertical-menu li {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, are you not allowed to use any CSS3 features, or just flexbox and grid?

Comment: I am not allowed to you use any css3 features

Comment: It is like asking "How to add style without adding CSS to a web page?". Well, you can still do it by rearranging your HTML and using margin and padding instead of positioning but that will not be ideal and responsive for multiple device sizes.

Comment: I understand you but this is the task I got, and I'm kind of stuck

Comment: @vturkovic. Why those specific requirements?  Seems odd.  Or are you targeting old skool Internet Explorer?  Ha.

Comment: Yes our clients are using old browsers, and this task is like exercise for not using css3 and other advanced styling techniques

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this using a `table`.**

Here is how I might accomplish it (click the 'Full page' link to see how the sidebar is vertically centered regardless of screen height):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.minimum-height {
  height: 0;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
}

.header ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2b3b75;
}

.header li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header li:hover {
  background: #3d53a3;
}

.vertical-menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2b3b75;
}

.vertical-menu li {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.vertical-menu li:hover {
  background: #3d53a3;
}

.footer {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #424242;
}

.footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer li:hover {
  background: #646464;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="minimum-height">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="header">
          <ul>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 2</li>
            <li>ITEM 3</li>
            <li>ITEM 4</li>
            <li>ITEM 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="main"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="vertical-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 2</li>
            <li>ITEM 3</li>
            <li>ITEM 4</li>
            <li>ITEM 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="minimum-height">
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="footer">
          <ul>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 2</li>
            <li>ITEM 3</li>
            <li>ITEM 4</li>
            <li>ITEM 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, creative solution, but I forgot to note it needs to be done using just div ul li

Comment: @vturkovic are you able to use `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, etc.?

Comment: No I'm not allowed to use, also no vh vw because its css3

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do to help you. You need to change your styling like

```
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #ccc;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    .header ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      background: #2b3b75;
    }
    .header li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .header li:hover {
      background: #3d53a3;
    }
    .vertical-menu {
      padding: 11.2% 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .vertical-menu ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      background: #2b3b75;
      width: fit-content;
      float: right;
    }
    .vertical-menu li {
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .vertical-menu li:hover {
      background: #3d53a3;
    }
    .footer {
    }
    .footer ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      background: #424242;
    }
    .footer li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .footer li:hover {
      background: #646464;
    }
</style>
```

And now you need to change the `.vertical-menu` `padding` according to the multiple device sizes if you need. You can do so using media query.

Comment: Is `fit-content` relevant for the answer to work? Because that feature is css sizing 4